# using static wordpress login form on front page but links to another wp install?

Tags: php, wordpress

Ok heres the senarrio, i have 4 wordpress installs as follows

top level = mysite.com/      *main site;
1st level = mysite.com/site1 *1st site
2st level = mysite.com/site2 *2nd site
3st level = mysite.com/site3 *3rd site

The front page on the main site has login forms to each of the three sub sites.
each site has different users, settings, content etc...

ie:

form 1
username & pass submit / form action="mysite.com/site1/wp-login.php"

form 2
username & pass submit / form action="mysite.com/site2/wp-login.php"

form 3
username & pass submit / form action="mysite.com/site3/wp-login.php"

when trying to login to any site, it will take the username/pass, submit the form
but come back to the front page were it first loaded, and not directing the user to the 
control panel /siteX/

is this something that can be done? or would this require some other way of thinking.
using links to the actual page instead of having the 3 login forms on the one page..?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably want Sidebar Login: http://blue-anvil.com/download/?did=28
If you use this,  the user is not redirected to the backend.

I would also advice you to look at [WPMU](http://wpmu.org/) if you are having multiple sites.

**Update**
You would have to edit the plugin to include a dropdown list, where you could select which site to login to.

Comment: the WPMU install was the first case we were going for, although our wp-member plugin isnt supported for this, hence the multiple wp installs.. which is good because each mini site requires different usernames and passwords for each.. if you sign up under site1, that give access to that only, not the other, & vice versa...

but thanks for the input anyway guys. cheers.
ill have to find another way..

Comment: It's not a problem having what you want with WPMU. There is a plugin for that too ;o)

Comment: I work with WPMU a lot & although MU has it's own set of quirks, it sounds like what you're shooting for MU would take care of. That, and around WP 3.0, WP & WPMU will merge, so it might be easier for you to make the switch now, then having to later down the road. Just a thought

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the URLs for each installation is set to the correct value under Settings->General

Comment: each install has been setup with the proper urls

main site // www.mysite.com/
mini site 1 // www.mysite.com/site1
mini site 2 // www.mysite.com/site2
mini site 3 // www.mysite.com/site3

the front page is a wordpress install although all that dose is produce a few static pages, which don't change much, and the main homepage, which is a page template, and holds the 3 login forms each action on each form varies, to include a link to wp-login.php for each mini site: but im thinking, wordpress doesn't like the fact that its being logged into from somewhere outside the wp install, 4 security etc..